# Is it possible to disable the "sceening" or "dimming" of the title bar in Office 365 Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

During multiple windows (let's say emails in outlook. For example, the software intentionally "dims" the title bar to indicate "inactive" windows.

This intentional idea of dimming the title bar works as intended BUT greys out the window controls (minimise,maximise,exit) in the process.

Is it possible to disable this action? I understand some of us may want an indication of window state, however I would much rather SEE ALL window controls regardless of active state, in this way I can work the windows as originally intended.
It would seem logical to use a modified or different method for window active state that does not affect actual controls of windows visually the way that it does.

[Image showing the very dimmed window controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgbiM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, sorry. This is a built-in non-configurable feature.

Comment: Really? Feature? so......removing spokes from a wheel to make "indicators" would be a "feature" ?I reckon it is the most rediculous thing ever to hide controls to the most basic function of the invention of windows period. I say leave the wheel round is was fine when first discovered - dont mess with it! I would have thought the core intention of improving programs would be to IMPROVE not "take back" functionality by HIDING actual controls.......